# How do i move one sub div from another div and put beside it?

Tags: html, css

We have product page like [advertising link removed]. How do i move below part as shown in 1st image to beside the main div.

[image]

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to move one div next to another div. One way of doing it would be to include the two divs into one bigger div (container) and use flex in this bigger div (with flex-direction set to row).
This way you can have both elements next to each other.

Example:

HTML:

```
<div class="makeThisFlex">
  <div id="main"></div>
  <div id="addToCart"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.makeThisFlex{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: I used above one but not useful. I need some part of the div need to be side but instead all parts comes into row if i use above method

Comment: <div class="makeThisFlex">
  <div id="main"></div>
  <div id="addToCart"> lub lub <div class="no"> lub2 </div></div>  here i want lub2 beside lublub . <div> lub3 </div> 
</div>

Comment: My bad, I thought you wanted to know a way to get the elements represented next to each other in one row. 
If you only want a part of it to be on the side, you can put them into a separate div and put the flex on that one you want the elements sorted next to each other (in one row). If you want the elements underneath each other, you can use flex-direction: column. You could also use a grid to layout your elements if you are trying to make the exact image above.

Comment: The code sample below places lub2 besides lublub using flexbox on both the id and the class:

**HTML**:
`<div class="makeThisFlex"> 
    <div id="main"></div> 
    <div class="oneLine">
      <div id="addToCart"> lub lub <div class="no">lub2 </div></div> 
    </div>
    <div> lub3 </div> 
  </div>`

**CSS**:
 `.makeThisFlex{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#addToCart{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}`

Edit: sorry for the bad layout, I'm quite new to this.